Characters limit on request for LLama3.1:8b running on Ollama
I'm currently running the LLama 3.1:8B model using the Ollama Docker container. My context window has the following structure:

Bot Personality
Bot Directives
Conversation (an array of messages)

I have a procedure that checks the total number of characters/tokens and trims the conversation (starting from the oldest messages) to fit within the context window. From what I've found online, the context window for LLama 3.1:8B is 128k tokens, which should equate to around 512,000 characters:more than enough for my use case.
However, I'm running into an issue where, after a certain number of messages, my bot starts losing its personality and directives. I suspect that Ollama might be truncating part of the context from the top. When I queried the bot, it mentioned having a 2048 character limit per message and trimming from the top when exceeding it (which would explain the problem).
Here are my questions:

Isn't Ollama stateless and therefore supposed to receive the full
context with every request?
If I need to set Ollama to track the conversation state and just send the new messages, how do I do it?
How can I ensure that the personality and directives stay fixed while only the conversation part gets trimmed?
Am I missing something in my setup or approach?

For reference, here's how I'm starting my Ollama instance:
docker run -it --rm --gpus=all -v /LLM/model/ollama:/root/.ollama:z -p 11434:11434 --name ollama ollama/ollama
docker exec -it ollama ollama pull llama3.1:8b


For those having the same problem, I might have found a solution:
While models like LLaMA 3.1:8B can support large context windows (up to 128k tokens), the default context window size in Ollama is 2048 tokens. To utilize a larger context window, you need to adjust the num_ctx parameter. For example, to set a 32k token context window:

Create a Modelfile:
  FROM llama3.1:8b
  PARAMETER num_ctx 32768


Apply the Modelfile:
ollama create -f Modelfile llama3.1:8b


Be aware that increasing the context window size requires more memory and computational resources. Ensure your hardware can accommodate the larger context to prevent performance issues.
